# Como hacer un response en json de API REST C#

Tags: c#, json, api

Estoy aprendiendo a hacer apis en C# yo por mi parte ya se hacerlas en php Laravel. Esta respuesta la hice con Eloquem usando `BelongsTo()` pero no se como hacer que se vea asi en C#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si lo notan, ciudad es otra subconsulta de otro modelo dentro de la consulta del json principal.

Si quieren ver el codigo original del api que hice en laravel esta aqui: https://github.com/Wilmilcard/Prueba_Cheil

**-- EL PROBLEMA --**

Tengo un listado de Hoteles:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y un listado de Calificaciones que se le han hecho a los hoteles:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero que en la segunda imagen (las calificaciones) no me sala el campo `Hotel_Id` si no el objeto del hotel, si en la imagen 2 dice 104 en el campo `Hotel_Id` pues que no salga el 104 si no el hotel como tal... asi como lo hice en Laravel, que no me sale el codigo de la ciudad si no la informacion completa en la ciudad

Comment: Y el código que has intentado con C#?

Comment: Es que no se ni como buscar documentacion, ¿por donde puedo empezar?. he preguntado acerca de Apis en C#, pero las que hacen son muy sencillas y no enseñan eso

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que armar la estructura de tus modelos primero, por ejemplo tendrias el modelo Hotel, Categoria, Ciudad y Calificacion

```
        public class Categoria
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Nombre { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class Ciudad
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Nombre { get; set; }
            public string Cod { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class Hotel
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public double Precio { get; set; }
            public string Foto1 { get; set; }
            public string Foto2 { get; set; }
            public string Foto3 { get; set; }
            public Ciudad CiudadOrigen { get; set; }
            public Categoria CategoriaHotel { get; set; }
        }

        public class Calificacion
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public Hotel HotelCalificado { get; set; }
            public int Nota { get; set; }
            public string Comentario { get; set; }
        }
```

Lo que quieres devolver es una Lista de la clase Calificacion en tu controller

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Calificaciones()
        {
            List<Calificacion> listaCalificaciones = ObtenerDatos();

            return listaCalificaciones;
        }
```

El ***ObtenerDatos()*** es un metodo que debes crear y es lo que retorna los datos ya sea de la base de datos o de algun archivo. Pero eso seria la estructura basica para resolver este problema

Te quedaria investigar obtener datos desde una base de datos, usar un ORM, que recomiendo Entity Framework, LINQ para consultar tus datos, Inyeccion de dependencia, Crear Servicios y consumirlos en el controller y con eso tienes lo basico para empezas.

Links de interes
(ORM+Entity Framework Core (blog de 5 partes)) https://medium.com/dottech/conociendo-entity-framework-core-v-6ddf76412709

(LINQ)
https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/introduccion-rapida-a-linq-con-c-sharp.aspx

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/walkthrough-writing-queries-linq

(Inyeccion de dependencia) https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/que-es-la-inyeccion-de-dependencias-y-como-funciona.aspx

https://geeks.ms/jorge/2019/02/06/inyeccion-de-dependencias-en-asp-net-core-i/

Saludos y exitos

Comment: +1. Buena respuesta. Lo único que podría hacerla mejor es agregar los links a la documentación oficial para cada uno de los conceptos que mencionas en tu último párrafo.

Comment: @Arriel gracias por el feedback, lo voy a editar